# Getting OutOfMemoryError in my code

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, out-of-memory

I am new to Xamarin android and for below code am getting `OutOfMemoryException`. Here `profilebitMap` is a `Bitmap` and `mProfileImage` is an `ImageView`. I have tried this with using block and dispose/recycle methods also but still getting the same error after multiple returns to the image page. Please help me in this.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(profile.Image))
{
    string[] fileExtension = profile.Image.Split('/');
    string _imagePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_documentsPath.ToString(), profile.ID + fileExtension[fileExtension.Length - 1]);

    if (File.Exists(_imagePath))
    {
        profilebitMap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeFileAsync(_imagePath);
        //profilebitMap = Util.Base64ToBitmap(appPreferencce.getAccessKey(profile.Image));
    }
    else
    {
        profilebitMap = Util.GetImageBitmapFromUrl(profile.Image, appPreferencce.getAccessKey("username"), appPreferencce.getAccessKey("password"));
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            profilebitMap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            var imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes(_imagePath, imageBytes);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    profilebitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.ApplicationContext.Resources, Resource.Drawable.dummyuser);
}
CircularDrawable d = new CircularDrawable(profilebitMap,
                  (int)Util.ConvertDpToPx(ApplicationContext, margin),
                  Util.ConvertDpToPx(ApplicationContext, strokeWidth),
                  new Android.Graphics.Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.normal3)));
mProfileImage.SetBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel, you can use libraries that load you pictures in few lines. You should take a look to the awesome library [Picasso](https://components.xamarin.com/view/square.picasso).

Bye

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the OutOfMemoryException we should use BitmapFactory.Options class.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

**Setting the inJustDecodeBounds property to true while decoding avoids memory allocation, returning null for the bitmap object but setting outWidth, outHeight and outMimeType.**

Now that the image dimensions are known, they can be used to decide if the full image should be loaded into memory or if a subsampled version should be loaded instead.

For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384. Loading this into memory uses 0.75MB rather than 12MB for the full image.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Please follow this url   https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html